# Heroku stop`ed working after linux virtual machine crashed

Tags: heroku

Hi I have my Linux as a virtual machine. When I was making heroku run rake db:seed it creshed and was shut down. After I run it again when I try to seed heroku I get:

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/rails_pro/vofr$ heroku run
 !   Error in heroku-run:
 !   Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
 !   See /home/saasbook/.heroku/error.log for more info.
```

And this is my error-log:

```
2016/02/29 17:23:27 heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
NULNULNULNULNULNUL.....NUL

29 21:26:16 Error during run:null
2016/02/29 21:26:16 TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at [eval]:36:28
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at node.js:544:27
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end I ended with totally removing the heroku.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku
sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku-toolbelt
rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
rm -rf ~/.heroku
```

and then :

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
heroku --version
```